# Ip Forwarding: wlan0 <=> eth0: without NetworkManager?

Tags: networking, network-interface, hostapd

I enabled ip-forwarding between my interfaces **wlan0** and **eth0** :

- in /etc/sysctl.conf
- `sh "echo 1 > proc/etc..."`
- 3 iptables rules.

> IpTables rules:

```
sudo iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o wlan0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT 
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
```

> Interfaces:

- **wlan0** is joinable by clients
- **eth0** is connected to the Internet

> Tools & config:

- hostapd
- dhcpd (with `option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8;, 8.8.4.4;`
- iptables

  ---

That done, when a client joins **wlan0**, s/he cannot browse the WWW *Error, not connected to Internet*. **But** he can ping sites (`ping google.fr`, `ping 75.XX.XX.XX`) with success.

I removed Network Manager (cause of conflicts with hostapd, at boot). Is Network Manager needed to make it work ?

Comment: Check if a wireless client receives a DNS configuration from dhcpd correctly. If you don't run a DNS server, you should run it or push some public DNS servers to the client, i.e. google ones. `option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;`

Comment: @Tim Thank you. Checked: In dhcpd, i exactly use `option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;`. I confirm DNS is solving well, cause in case of **redirecting all** (instead of **ip forwarding all**), only solved domain-name are redirected, unsolved ones display error.

Comment: Check the MTU values on both interfaces.  It is likely the culprit.  You can verify by increasing the ping packet size at some point likely around 2KB you won't be able to ping from a wireless client - this is a typical manifestation of the MTU mismatch.

Comment: @galaxy Thanks. `ifconfig`=>eth0 MTU:1500 ; wlan0 MTU:1500 . What should I do ? ( lo MTU:65536)